# Vim Highlight Problems

Tags: ubuntu, vim, highlight

I'm working with nesC language using vim under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

My problem is when I'm editing the codes, highlighting works ok (like on the first picture), but when I save, quit and open the file again, the highlighting disappears (like on the second one).

[image]
[image]

Thank you all very much!

PS: I've set the syntax on. When I read other's codes, the highlighting works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vim` highlights syntax of existing files based on file extension (which one do you use?). Fortunately, there can be some extensions that allow you to fix it. Probably [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=899) is such an extension. [This](http://beerpla.net/2008/04/02/how-to-add-a-vim-file-extension-to-syntax-highlighting/) can be helpful, too. In short, they describe a method to make a highlighting for an extension of your choice to work as for C++, for instance. From the post:

> After digging around I found the solution. Add the following to ~/.vimrc (the vim configuration file):
>
> ```
> syntax on
> filetype on
> au BufNewFile,BufRead *.lmx set filetype=xml
> ```

Comment: actually i‘ve follow the instruction from [link](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1847)